# Unable to install Nvidia Drivers in Kali Linux (no version information available required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20)

Tags: nvidia, kali-linux

I am recently installed Kali Linux 1.0.9a. I have Nvidia GEForce 210 graphic card, so I try to install nvidia drivers by doing the following procedure specified [here](http://www.free4net.com/2014/05/installing-nvidia-drivers-in-kali-linux.html)

```
apt-get install  nvidia-kernel-dkms
```

After rebooting I am unable to open the GUI. The error printed is:

```
Nov  9 18:13:56 kali nm-dispatcher[948]: systemctl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20)
Nov  9 18:16:48 kali systemd[1]: kmod-static-nodes.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov  9 18:16:48 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
Nov  9 18:16:48 kali systemd[1]: Unit kmod-static-nodes.service entered failed state
```

What does this error mean and how can I resolve it?

**UPDATE:**

I removed all Nvidia components and tried to open the GUI, but still got the same error message.

```
apt-get purge nvidia*
```

I downloaded the Nvidia driver from the [official website](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/79413/en-us) and installed, but no luck. I got the same error message again.

```
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.58.run
./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.58.run
```

Comment: i don't know what package corrupted but i understand that adding the dev-main repository of Kali Linux take me into this problem.
Never add dev-main repository unless you know what you are doing. it is not problem with the Nvidia graphic card but the problem with developer packages itself.
A clean Kali Linux installation with out dev-main repository solved my problem.

Comment: It's not a duplicate question. The question is specific to Nvidia Drivers and the question's description does not say 'it's so hard to set up Kali Linux in any way'. Moreover the answers to the question 'Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?' is more in general way.  You better check it again before marking it as 'Duplicate Question'.

Comment: Moreover people are down voting whenever they see this question. My question is not about "Linux is Hard" or some newbie crying for help because Linux is hard. Stop making the questions duplicate for some random reason. I mentioned the issue so clearly and it's more about NVIDIA driver support for Linux.